# Getx display wrong

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I use Getx in flutter and request the back-end carousel image data in the onInit method of the Controller file. Then the image is not displayed when the simulator starts, but it can be displayed by switching the page, or it can be displayed by re-saving it in vscode

[image]

[image]

It doesn't work for me outside the container widget or the swiper widget plus Obx.

Comment: make the list observable and show a loader indicator whilst the data is loading.

Comment: 1. (declare) RxList<Swipper> swiperList =<Swipper>[].obs ;  ( remember Swipper is amodel class, if u just wanna get the image only then use  RxList<String> swiperList =<String>[].obs ;  )  2. (use like this) Obx(() =>Swiper() );

Comment: @JBJason thanks, your first solution is correct, i  changed swiperList to swiperList.obs and it did not take effect,but changed it to RxList swiperList = RxList() and added Obx to the swiper Widget and it can be displayed.

Comment: @JBJason Is it because simple data types can be added directly with .obs, while complex ones require the use of corresponding responsive life methods?